# Reference error

Tags: c#, dnx, asp.net-core-1.0, dnx50

I am getting reference error after i created new project in Asp.net core:

[image: dnx4.5.1]

[image: dnx 5.0]
[image: My dnvm list]

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that you have dependencies in your project that need to be download. The command `dnu restore` will download the dependencies and add them to your app package directory. You have to run the command from the folder that contains the app (the one that contains the `project.json`).

To know more about it follow this posts:

- [Working with DNX Projects](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html#restoring-packages)
- [DNX Utility](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-utility).

Comment: While the link might answer the question you should include the relevant information in your answer.